# What does the Haitian Constitution provide for in the case of the death of the President?

Tags: president, constitution, prime-minister, succession, haiti

According to a statement on the [Juno 7 news website](https://www.juno7.ht/jovenel-moise-blesse-mortellement-lors-dune-attaque/) by interim Prime Minister Claude Joseph, the President of Haiti, Jovenel Moïse, was assassinated during the night between the 6th and 7th of July 2021.

[The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-news/2021/07/07/haitian-president-jovenel-moise-assassinated-official-residence/), reporting on this story, mentions that Joseph "said he was now in charge of the country".

How can the Prime Minister take over the role of President? Is this in line with the Constitution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Up until 2012, Article 149 of the [Haitian Constitution](https://pdba.georgetown.edu/Constitutions/Haiti/haiti1987.html) used to obligate the National Assembly, convened by the Prime Minister, to invest the President of the Supreme Court of the Republic (or, if unavailable, another senior judge in order of seniority) with the duties of President of the Republic - with new elections to be held between 45 and 90 days later.

However, the constitution was [amended in 2012](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Haiti_2012.pdf?lang=en), and now reads:

> In case of vacancy of the Presidency of the Republic either by
> resignation, dismissal, death  or  in  case  of  physical  or  mental
> permanent  incapacity  duly  declared,  the Council  of  Ministers,
> under  the  presidency  of  the  Prime  Minister,  exercises
> the Executive Power until the election of another President.
>
> In  this
> case,  the  ballot  for  the  election  of  the  new  President  of
> the  Republic  for  the time  that  remains  to  complete  the  mandate
> takes  place  sixty  (60)  days  at  least  and one  hundred  twenty
> (120)  days  at  most  after  the  beginning  of  the  vacancy,
> in accordance with the Constitution and the electoral law.
>
> In  the  case
> where  the  vacancy  is  produced  from  the  fourth  year  of  the
> presidential mandate,  the  National  Assembly  meets  of  office
> within  the  sixty  (60)  days  which follow  the  vacancy  to  elect
> a  new  Provisional  President  of  the  Republic  for  the  time that
> remains to complete the mandate.

So, in this case, the Council of Ministers, led by interim Prime Minister Claude Joseph exercises executive power until the office of president is filled.

As President Moïse began his mandate on February 7th, 2017, the last paragraph applies, and the National Assembly (a joint session of the two houses of parliament) will within sixty days elect a new provisional president until the end of Moïse's mandate in February 2022.

**However**

Two issues complicate the matter - firstly, President Moïse had named Claude Joseph's replacement, Ariel Henry, on July 5th. Although Henry had not been sworn in, the Constitution doesn't mention any such requirement to take office. Henry's supporters argue that this makes him the legitimate Prime Minister.

Secondly, Moïse was elected in the 2015 elections. He would normally have taken office on February 7th, 2016, however, the run-off election was delayed until October 2016 - with an interim President holding office in the meantime. Opponents of Moïse suggest that his mandate should have expired on February 7th, 2021, five years after he *should* have taken office. The relevant article in the constitution is Article 134-2:

> The  presidential  election  takes  place  on  the  last  Sunday  of
> October  of  the  fifth  year of the presidential mandate.
>
> The
> president  elected  enters  into  his  functions  on  7  February
> following  the  date  of his  election.  In  the  case  where  the
> ballot  cannot  take  place  before  7  February,  the president
> elected  enters  into  his  functions  immediately  after  the
> validation  of  the ballot  and  his  mandate  is  considered  to  have
> commenced  on  7  February  of  the  year of the election.

Comment: There are 2 controversies which complicate the situation. 1) Ariel Henry was appointed as Prime Minister by the President a day before his assassination. 2) Opposition claimed that Moïse's term ended in February 2021.

Comment: @Neith definitely - although Henry had been named by Moïse, I think I'm right in saying he hadn't been sworn in yet? I'm not aware of the full story behind the end of term claims - the constitution seems pretty clear that the president's term is five years

Comment: I don’t have any special knowledge on Haitian politics, I just read about it in Wikipedia. The article about the assassination discusses the term limit issue. I guess the opposition may raise it once again now. As for Henry, it says he was not sworn in yet, but doesn’t say whether he will be, and whether he would become Acting President then. I just think these issues should be mentioned in the answer, to make it more complete.

Comment: @Neith yeah, you're right. I'll do a bit of reading and update :) thanks